# Ggplotly() hides secondary y-axis created with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have the dataframe below and Im trying to create a double y-axis plot with `ggplot2` and then turn it to `ggplotly()`. The issue is that while the plot is created normally using `ggplot2` when I turn it to `ggplotly()` object the secondary y-axis is disapperaed.

```
df2<-structure(list(year = c(1951, 1954, 1955, 1957, 1958, 1960, 1961, 
1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 
1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 
1986, 1988, 1989, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019), 
    Scope = c(4, 3, 5, 27, 6, 13, 6, 6, 24, 1, 21, 24, 32, 57, 
    18, 1, 43, 39, 8, 58, 68, 78, 7, 20, 26, 4, 12, 19, 8, 37, 
    35, 51, 209, 478, 395, 355, 453, 457, 262, 148, 196, 180, 
    367, 283, 360, 414, 175, 330, 314, 446, 428, 163, 213, 165, 
    307, 231, 53, 189, 18, 104, 39), count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 14, 26, 18, 25, 23, 26, 19, 13, 12, 
    13, 20, 22, 24, 25, 14, 21, 15, 22, 18, 8, 13, 6, 11, 9, 
    5, 5, 1, 3, 1), fiveYears = c("1951-1955", "1951-1955", "1951-1955", 
    "1957-1961", "1957-1961", "1957-1961", "1957-1961", "1962-1965", 
    "1962-1965", "1962-1965", "1962-1965", "1967-1971", "1967-1971", 
    "1967-1971", "1967-1971", "1967-1971", "1972-1977", "1972-1977", 
    "1972-1977", "1972-1977", "1972-1977", "1972-1977", "1979-1982", 
    "1979-1982", "1979-1982", "1979-1982", "1983-1986", "1983-1986", 
    "1983-1986", "1983-1986", "1988-1992", "1988-1992", "1988-1992", 
    "1988-1992", "1993-1998", "1993-1998", "1993-1998", "1993-1998", 
    "1993-1998", "1993-1998", "1999-2003", "1999-2003", "1999-2003", 
"1999-2003", "1999-2003", "2004-2008", "2004-2008", "2004-2008", 
    "2004-2008", "2004-2008", "2009-2013", "2009-2013", "2009-2013", 
    "2009-2013", "2009-2013", "2014-2019", "2014-2019", "2014-2019", 
    "2014-2019", "2014-2019", "2014-2019"), Scope_min = c(3, 
    3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 35, 35, 35, 35, 148, 148, 148, 
    148, 148, 148, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 175, 175, 175, 175, 
    175, 163, 163, 163, 163, 163, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18), Scope_max = c(5, 
    5, 5, 27, 27, 27, 27, 24, 24, 24, 24, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
    78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 26, 26, 26, 26, 37, 37, 37, 37, 478, 
    478, 478, 478, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 367, 367, 367, 
    367, 367, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 428, 428, 428, 428, 428, 
    231, 231, 231, 231, 231, 231)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -61L))
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p<-ggplot(df2, aes(x=year)) +
  
  geom_point( aes(y=Scope), size=2, color=y1Color) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Scope_min, ymax=Scope_max), width=.1)+
  geom_point( aes(y=count), size=2, color=y2Color) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(
    
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "Scope",
    
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, name="pta")
  ) + 
  
  theme_minimal() +
  
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = y1Color, size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = y2Color, size=13)
  ) +
  
  ggtitle("Temperature down, price up")
ggplotly(p)
```